# pasar una variable de ajax a php y redireccionar

Tags: ajax

Saludos mi gente de stackoverflow, he buscado en todas partes y no encuentro como enviar el valor de una variable capturada con un click desde ajax a php y que me redirecciones al php con el que voy a desarrollar esos datos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabla').load('tabla.php');
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Consulta tabla SQL</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
 <center>
  <label>
   <h3>Consulta MySQL</h3>
  </label>  
 </center>
 <div id="tabla"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
 var pagina= 
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){ 
        var datos = $(this).prop('id');

      alert('El Valor del ID es...:'+datos);
      
        })

     });
```

```html
<?php 
$conect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prueba');

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<br>
 <div class="container col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr class="success" align="center">
     <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
     <td><strong>NOMBRE</strong></td>
     <td><strong>APELLIDOS</strong></td>
     <td><strong>NIVEL</strong></td>
     <td><strong>TELEFONO</strong></td>
    </tr>
    
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   <?php
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM usuario";
   $result=mysqli_query($conect, $sql);
   while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

     <tr>
     <td id="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>"><?php echo $mostrar['id']?></td>
     <td id="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>"><?php echo $mostrar['nombres']?></td>
     <td id="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>"><?php echo $mostrar['apellidos']?></td>
     <td id="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>"><?php echo $mostrar['nivel']?></td>
     <td id="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>"><?php echo $mostrar['telefono']?></td>
    </tr>
    
    <?php 

   }
    ?>
   

   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

y quiero que el resultado se despliegue aqui:

```html
<?php 
$conect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prueba');

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title>Perfil del Usuario</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="container col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center"><strong>Perfil General del Usuario</strong> </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <?php
 $datos = $_POST['datos'];
 
  $log = mysqli_query($conect,"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id='$datos'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($log)>0) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($log);
}
  ?>
 
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <th class="success col-sm-3">ID</th>
  <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="success col-sm-3">NOMBRES</th>
  <td><?php echo $row['nombres'] ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="success col-sm-3">APELLIDOS</th>
  <td><?php echo $row['apellidos'] ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="success col-sm-3">GRADO</th>
  <td><?php echo $row['grado'] ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th class="success col-sm-3">TELEFONO</th>
  <td><?php echo $row['telefono'] ?></td>
 </tr>

 </table>
 </div>
  
 </div>
 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco toda su ayuda..

Comment: por mas que leo no encuentro la parte donde envias la variable con ajax a php

Comment: Ese es el punto. No se como hacerlo. Agradeceria que me hechara una mano. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es muy sencillo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){ 
        var datos = $(this).prop('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'tu_archivo_php.php',
            data: {'datos': datos}
            success:function(resp){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

me comentas como te fue o si tienes alguna otra inquietud, si te funciona no te olvides de calificar :)

Comment: Hola Mauricio he copiado el block de codigo y modifique la url a perifl.php y no hace nada en el inspector del explorador me dice esto, "Un XMLHttpRequest síncrono en el hilo principal está desaprobado por sus efectos negativos en la experiencia del usuario final. Para más ayuda vea  http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/", me gustaria que lo corrieras a ver que te dice porque he intentado todo. Saludos.

Comment: Mauricio mil gracias hermano, esta resuelto, despues de "success:function (resp) " agregue $('table').html(resp); y listo.